# Add or replace an item in a nested association list

Tags: list, emacs

From the docs:

> The variable `window-system-default-frame-alist` is an alist of
>   elements `(WINDOW-SYSTEM . ALIST)`, where `WINDOW-SYSTEM` is a
>   window system symbol and `ALIST` is a frame parameter alist.

Let's say I want to change the frame parameter alist for the X Window System, so that it contains the element `(font . "Monospace-11")`, but I don't want multiple `font` elements in that alist.

So what do I do? Basically, I go over the alists, remove the element I want to replace/add, and then add the element.  This is the code:

```
(let ((x-frame-alist (alist-get 'x window-system-default-frame-alist)))
  (cl-acons 'x (cl-acons 'font "Monospace-11"
                         (cl-remove (cl-assoc 'font x-frame-alist)
                                    x-frame-alist))
            (cl-remove `(x . ,x-frame-alist)
                       window-system-default-frame-alist)))
```

Then the result must be assigned to the symbol `window-system-default-frame-alist`.  But somehow all this looks overly complicated.  Surely there must be a simpler solution.

Comment: Are you sure you need to replace that alist entry, instead of just adding a new one with the same key at the front of the alist? That's one of the advantages of using an alist: an entry with the same key shadows entries with that key that are further down the alist. IOW, why not just add your "replacement" entry to the alist?

Comment: @Drew I don't need to, it just doesn't feel to right to simply add an entry without checking if there's already the same entry in the list, otherwise the list could grow out of control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
(push '(font . "Monospace-11")
      (alist-get 'x window-system-default-frame-alist))
```

or

```
(setf (alist-get 'font (alist-get 'x window-system-default-frame-alist))
      "Monospace-11")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `push` to set the new font, and `assq-delete-all` to remove the old settings.

```
(progn
  (setq frame-alist '((x . ((font . "remove")
                            (other . "d")
                            (font . "remove")
                            (other . "c")))
                      (w32 . ((font . "keep")))))

  (setq x-change-font (assq-delete-all 'font (alist-get 'x frame-alist)))
  (push '(font . "wanted") x-change-font)
  (setq frame-alist
        (mapcar
         (lambda (elem) (if (eq (car elem) 'x) `(x . ,x-change-font) elem))
         frame-alist ))
  frame-alist)
```

Returns:

```
((x   (font . "wanted") (other . "d") (other . "c"))
 (w32 (font . "keep")))
```